# Does learning Metasploit help me in reverse engineering and malware analysis?

Tags: disassembly, malware, assembly, buffer-overflow, metasploit

I learned basis of assembly language with, both, AT&T and Intel style. After that I gone through buffer overflow and how to use shellcode with it. Should I go for [Metasploit](http://www.metasploit.com/) now?

Comment: Depends on, if you want to focus on reversing, analysing malware, metasploit won't help you. You can use metasploit to test exploits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nope. Metasploit is a pentester framework, not a reversing/malware-dev framework. Instead, you should master a debugger ([IDA](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/debugger/), [Radare2](http://radare.org/y/), [OllyDbg](http://www.ollydbg.de/), etc) and at least one scripting language ([Python](http://www.python.org/) or [Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/)).

Comment: Does Python or Ruby helps in RE?

Comment: Scripting language does help for automation. And, moreover, most of the tools in RE are coded in one of these languages (easy prototyping and quite robust in the long term).

Answer (score 4):

No.
               
 
 
 
 
 
​

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. Actually, I got your point, but can accept only one answer.

Comment: _"This does not provide an answer to the question."_ -- Are you serious? :)

Answer (score 3):

Metasploit can generate some malicious files, such as PDFs.  Malware analysis isn't necessarily just Windows PE files so it might be a good idea to look into other file formats.  Metaploit could be useful to generate your own samples to analyze.

Msfvenom might be interesting to you as well.  It is a tool that generates shellcode given a payload.  Generated shellcode might not always be the best though.

Answer (score 2):

You may find other people code useful and metasplot is good to test and understand how things can be exploited.

For reversing there are alot of videos and sildes that other people have released explaining how they achieved there goals